# Plotting line with gaussian noise

Tags: python, gaussian

My task is to write a function named random_line that creates x and y data for a line with y direction random noise that has a normal distribution N(0,σ^2):
y=mx+b+N(0,σ^2).

My question right now is more math related I guess than programming related.  To create my ydata points, I am guessing I would have to plug in my array of x data points into the above equation.  However, I have no idea how to calculate the N(0,σ^2) part.  Any ideas?

```
def random_line(m, b, sigma, size=10):
    """Create a line y = m*x + b + N(0,sigma**2) between x=[-1.0,1.0]

    Parameters
    ----------
    m : float
        The slope of the line.
    b : float
        The y-intercept of the line.
    sigma : float
        The standard deviation of the y direction normal distribution noise.
    size : int
        The number of points to create for the line.

    Returns
    -------
    x : array of floats
        The array of x values for the line with `size` points.
    y : array of floats
        The array of y values for the lines with `size` points.
    """
    xdata = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,size)
    ydata = 'xxxxxxx'
    return xdata, ydata
```

Comment: Check out `scipy.stats` for ways to generate values from different distributions, for random normally distributed values you want `scipy.stats.norm.rvs(size=whatever)`

Answer (score 2):

Using the distributions in `scipy.stats` it's easy to create the normally-distributed errors in a way that allows you to easily add them to your other numpy arrays like `xdata`:

```
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_line(m, b, sigma, size=10):
    xdata = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,size)
    # Generate normally distributed random error ~ N(0, sigma**2)
    errors = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=sigma, size=size)
    ydata = m * xdata + b + errors
    return xdata, ydata

xs, ys = random_line(2, 3, 2, size=50)

# Plot to see how closely the values fit the 
#   original line
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xs, ys, 'o')
ax.plot(xs, 2 * xs + 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out random.normalvariate in the Python standard library.